# Algolia for node.js and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, algolia

I have a problem right now, Algolia does provide a rich documentation regarding node.js but my problem right now are

1) how do i import mongodb database to algolia server? seems like they are showing how to use MySql database instead of Mongodb with node.js

2) Im using ejs to render the html, so do i need to query the value of a search using node.js or just let the clientside html handle it?

because with ejs I have to use

```
app.get("/testingSearch", function(req, res) {

  res.render('testing', { message: value});
})

app.post("/postSearch", function(req, res) {
  // some searching 
  var name = req.body.name;
  // algolia
});
```

Anyone who has an experience with algolia + node.js + mongodb , please lend me your advise. Thank you

Comment: this is the structure of the object you need to send https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#initial-import and this is where you can replace as you said the mysql query with its primary key to mongo document with its objectID https://www.algolia.com/doc/node#using-the-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### MongoDB

If you just want to have a complete replica of a collection, you can use the [Algolia's MongoDB connector](https://www.algolia.com/with/mongodb).

However, if you want to do a more advanced indexing, you should add algolia indexing calls alongside the calls to your database.

#### Rendering

Algolia has been designed to be used in your front-end. See [this FAQ entry](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/searching-from-the-front-end-or-the-back-end).
However, for SEO purposes, a back-end search might make sense to you. Since the JS client is isomorphic, you can mix the two pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't understand this context "You should add algolia indexing calls alongside the calls to your database."

Comment: Maybe if you could add some article or resources , it would be good

Comment: The best resource remains https://www.algolia.com/doc/node#using-the-api , even if the examples provided are using MySQL, you should grasp the idea. Creating a documentation for each association of [language, database] would be a huge task. If there is a blocking point for your implementation, you should probably open another question. :)